# Daisy chaining from laptop to two monitors

Tags: displayport, usb-c, daisychaining

I am setting up a home office and considered PA278CV's to be my displays. I'd like to buy two of them and daisy chain them from my laptop. Am I able to do it in this manner:

1. Laptop

   - USB-C to USB-C
2. Display #1

   - DisplayPort to DisplayPort
3. Display #2

Other option is to go for a dock, but I'd like to do it this way since PA278CV has the USB's to do this without a dock.

Comment: The link you've posted to deleted answer explicitly says dP 1.2 on the computer is required.